# Exception thrown in a referenced .dll how do I debug?

Tags: ajax, debugging, .net-3.5

I'm using watermark extenders on textboxes and an exception is being thrown from the AJAX Control Toolkit .dll. It's strange because this just started happening.

I tried debugging from the Ajax solution and Ajax examples (but with my code), but no dice.

Is there a way to step into the Ajax .dll from my solution to see where this is happening?

Comment: Is the source cdoe not available?

Comment: The source code is available but I can't reproduce the error from within it.

Comment: Is it possible the code you have is different to the compiled code in the .dll?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couldn't you just get the source for the Ajax Control Toolkit and include it as a project in your solution and then reference it?  You'd then be able to step into the code and if you really needed to, you can just put the precompiled one out when you deploy out.

Answer (score 2):

The source code for the AJAX Control Toolkit is available from:

http://www.codeplex.com/AjaxControlToolkit/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=16488

Just download and start debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include the AjaxControlToolkit project. Just open the file you need (in the VS instance where your code that currently breaks is), and set a breakpoint where appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a black box approach is more appropriate here.  You said that this error just started - what has changed in your environment to start this?  You may be headed down a rabbit hole by stepping through the code.  Can you deploy to a clean environment and not get the error?  Or, does it work in the dev but not the test environment?